# foldtext seems to be recalculated across all folds every time you move the cursor line

Tags: folding, foldtext, manual-folding, system, word-count

With manual folding.

Using a system call to put a line/char/word/ count for the text within each fold:

```
:set foldtext=system('wc',getline(v:foldstart+1,v:foldend))
```

the command works (if you ignore for now the need to strip trailing chars).

But every time you move the cursor up or down a line, when folds are closed, the cursor runs down the length of the screen, very slowly, going over each fold on its way, before coming back where it is supposed to be. It makes the whole command useless.

What's going wrong?

Comment: I suspect foldtext is being calculated frequently enough that you get a perf hit. You can try using a function and some internal counting procedures? With Vim9 this should be especially fast relative to the cost of subprocesses.

Comment: The same thing happens if you run it as a function to foldtext. It does indeed seem the foldtext is being recalculated every time you move the cursor line. Hard to imagine why this would be necessary.

Comment: @markling Are you saying the same thing happens even if you don't call `system()`?

Comment: It's not as slow if I don't call system(). If, just for example, I use `set foldtext=getline(v:foldstart+1,v:foldend)`, I can move the cursor without gvim pausing to burp everytime, but it still moves just perceptibly slowly -- seemingly milliseconds of delay that are enough to niggle like a persistent single rain drop - you know?

Comment: @markling Hmmm. I can't seem to reproduce this. Does it only happen with large files? Does it still happen for you if you start gvim with   `gvim --clean`?